# Problem getting Apache virtual hosting to work

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I'm trying to get Apache virtual hosting to work with an Amazon EC2 instance. My httpd.conf looks like the following

```
ServerName <elastic_ip>:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/site1
  ServerName www.site1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Where the elastic_ip is roughly like a static IP in Amazon-land. My problem is that the site is not loading properly. For example when I type the following in the browser address bar:

```
EC2-public-dns     .... this works and loads the virtual host site
www.EC2-public-dns .... this doesn't load and gives "The requested URL could not be        retrieved", i.e. not any default page
elastic-ip         .... same as above
www.elastic-ip     .... same as above
```

I don't have anything in the /etc/hosts file, perhaps I should? Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

---

Update: these are my setting in Godaddy now.

```
DNS Manager: Available 
A          @    el.as.tic.ip
CNAME      www  site1.com
CNAME      ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com  @
```

Comment: `CNAME   www   site1.com`  should probably be `CNAME    www    @` see the Adding or editing  CNAME records section in this document http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#cnames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working with [Name-Based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html). This requires that you have some method of mapping the `www.site1.com` name to the elastic IP address of your instance. You can do this using a hosts file but it would only be accessible from the instance itself. Normally you would arrange to have a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) [A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) or [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) record resolve to the Elastic IP address of your instance for the names you want your server to deliver.

```
www.site1.com.        CNAME  site1.com.
site1.com.            A      el.as.tic.ip
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - at my domain registrar (godaddy) I have a DNS A record already pointing to the elastic ip. Regarding the information in the "highlighted box" - this should go in the hosts file - is that correct?

Comment: www.EC2-public-dns should be a CNAME in the godaddy DNS pointing to the DNS A record for www.EC2-public-dns.

Comment: In the Zone file editor on Godaddy within the A record section I set the field "@" to el.as.tic.ip and within the CNAME section I set the "www" field to www.public-dns I guess I need to wait a while for this to update?

Comment: You probably  need to point the www field to the @ record [see here](http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#cnames)

Comment: Its now more than 12 hours since I updated the DNS records on godaddy, but yet I still can't reach the site via the domain name. Since I can access the site using the public dns of the EC2 instance, I'm assuming my Apache configuration is correct. So how would I go about debugging the current problem?

Comment: All working now - though one final thing, somehow I missed the fact I hadn't opened port 80! eik. All good now though